# How do I delete an LI tag on a click using the jquery widgets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery to implement a draggable LI object.  I want to be able to delete the image when the user clicks delete.  Here is the code below:

```
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" id="1">
    <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Click for details</h5>
    <A href="" onclick='return onShowTask("Sample Task");'><img src="graphics/task.png" width="96" height="72" /></a>
    <center>Sample Task</center>
    <a href="" onclick='return onShowTask("Sample Task");' title="View details" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View Details</a>
    <a href="" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with what you've tried

Comment: 1995 called. It wants its `<center>` tag back.

Comment: remember that and id cant start with a number if you want to validate your markup

Comment: @voigtan - it can in HTML5. Although looking at this code I'm guessing HTML5 isn't part of the issue :/

Comment: @j08691, what is so bad with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the delete button this will delete the parent li. I believe this is what your after.

```
$(".ui-icon-trash").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
});
```

Comment: How do I get the id of the li that was just deleted?

Comment: @stevelandiss store the $(this).parent("li") to a variable and get its id attribute from it before you remove it

Comment: voigtan, even though my LI tag has an id attribute, $(this).parent("li").getAttribute("id") is coming up as undefined

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(".ui-icon-trash").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("li").find("img").remove();
    return false;
})
```